# Regex for matching hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: c#, regex, hex, match

So I'm trying to figure out how to use regex to to match a hex string. The current regex I'm using is:

```
[^0]+
```

I want it to match: `50 6C 65 63 74 72 6F 6E 73`
given:

```
50 6C 65 63 74 72 6F 6E 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
64 35 75 73 70 73 34 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
52 61 79 74 69 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
63 38 63 61 70 73 34 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
92 B6 B3 F5 00 00 00 01 8A 68 58 DD 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

but it only matches `50`.

When using this hex string it works the way I want it to:

```
52 61 79 74 69 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
63 38 63 61 70 73 34 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
52 69 70 74 69 64 65 31 30 33 30 00 00 00 00 00 
64 32 75 73 70 73 34 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
B3 F4 0A 88 00 00 00 1F C0 95 41 99 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

matches `52 61 79 74 69 6E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused at how your regex is matching `50` and not just `5`. But in general, the problem with your regex is that it is just going until it hits a 0, and what you want is for it to go until you hit two consecutive zeros. The standard way to do this is with a look-around:

```
.+?(?= 00)
```

The `.+` will match any characters for as long as possible. The second part of the regular expression (called a positive lookahead) searches for two zeros and terminates the match just before the occurrence of the `00`. The reason for doing `.+?` instead of just `.+` is that the latter will match everything until the last `00`, whereas you only want everything up until the first `00`. The `?` converts the `.+` into a lazy regex, so it matches the minimum required rather than the maximum possible. In this case it means that it'll match until the first `00` instead of the last `00`.

Note that inside the look-around I included a space so that your match would not include a space at the end of the string. Not sure if that matters to you.

Comment: also you are right it was matching just 5 id + rep you if i could i just created my account so i cant and thank you for the explanation of how it works now i have a better understanding of regex

Comment: No problem, glad that helped

Answer (score 9):

**This will match number by number:**

```
[a-fA-F0-9]{2}
```

[Online example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b2%7d&i=50+6C+65+63+74+72+6F+6E+73+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+%0d%0a64+35+75+73+70+73+34+00+01+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+%0d%0a52+61+79+74+69+6E+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+%0d%0a63+38+63+61+70+73+34+00+01+00+00+00+00+00+00+00+%0d%0a92+B6+B3+F5+00+00+00+01+8A+68+58+DD+00+00+00+00+%0d%0a00+00+00+00+)

**This will match the whole string:**

```
^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}\s+)+
```

[Online example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%5Ba-fA-F0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%2B)%2B&i=50%206C%2065%2063%2074%2072%206F%206E%2073%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%20%0D%0A64%2035%2075%2073%2070%2073%2034%2000%2001%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%20%0D%0A52%2061%2079%2074%2069%206E%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%20%0D%0A63%2038%2063%2061%2070%2073%2034%2000%2001%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%20%0D%0A92%20B6%20B3%20F5%2000%2000%2000%2001%208A%2068%2058%20DD%2000%2000%2000%2000%20%0D%0A00%2000%2000%2000%20)

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
(?!00)[0-9A-F]{2}
```

Which says

1. Reject if it starts with 00
2. Accept if the value is 0-9 or A-F
3. Take two characters